# Question about going forth (while having children & wife)

Tags: marriage, children, lay-person

Do the scriptures somewhere mention that it's appropriate to go forth when having a wife & children?

According to the scriptures Gotama, the Buddha-to-be,  left his palace & his parents to reach enlightenment, but leaving one's parents is quite different than leaving one's wife and his child.

Reference to scriptures is highly appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99452/discussion-on-question-by-val-question-about-going-forth-while-having-children).

Answer (score 1):

When Rahula was born the Buddhisattava was contemplating to renouncing a householder's life hence he said "rāhulajāto bandhanaṃ jātaṃ", meaning "A rāhu is born, a fetter has arisen".

So a kid and a wife bind you to with the burden of responsibility. There were many monks who left householders life with families to become monks at the time of the Buddha. Even now in Buddhist countries, this happens.

Going forth is leaving aside ones household responsibilities to wife, children, parents, relatives and friends, so that one is free from these responsibilities, hence having more time to practice the dhamma.

Comment: Not responsibility, Nyom. For higher responsibility, beyond kamakuna. This is seen in such way just by those no faith yet, rejecting going forth. Total wrong perceived.